# Should I paste CDN links in a JS file or use a Bootstrap CDN plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I'm new to WP development and I don't have the experience to know if I should place CDN links in a JS file and enqueue it or use a nifty plugin such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/). What is best practice? What should I base my decision on?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on codetutsplus has everything you need to know. There is no need to use a plugin. Enqueuing them is pretty simple and is best practice.

[how to enqueue files in wordpress](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402)